# Give collaborator access to analytics only

Tags: parse-platform

We would like to be able to provide a collaborator with access to our analytics only. Is this possible?

It's quite important for our marketing and business development colleagues to be able to access analytics, while at the same time not have access to the data browser and cloud code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible currently on Parse.

You should raise this as a feature request on Parse developer forums https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/parse-developers